# Different collation between System and User databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, collation

Recently, I have came across a situation where I found there is different SQL Collation is set for System databases and user databases on a sql instance in production.

Like: Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS for master, tempdb,model and msdb.
    Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI for USER_DB's.

Would there be any problem with this type of collation settings?

Comment: And consider using a Contained Database to mitigate the problems. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is definitely a duplicate of [SQL Server default collation vs database with different collation - potential problems?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/239937/30859)

However, as that question was purely generic and this question specifies the two collations, I can at least clarify one of the issues raised in that other question:

> do you see any potential data loss?

In this case there is no potential data loss due to the only difference being a sensitivity (accent sensitivity), which affects sorting and comparisons, but not which character set is being used to store `VARCHAR` data.

Though, depending on how one defines "data loss", it should be pointed out (at least for the sake of thoroughness) that there is a possibility that a temp table is being used that contains a string column that is not being given an explicit collation when the temp table is created (either `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI` or `DATABASE_DEFAULT`, there is no appreciable difference between them here), and is thus using `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS`. That could lead to a query classifying two values as being different if they only differ in accents (well, and yes, also case, width, and kana-type), whereas using `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI` would classify them as being equal. This can return unexpected results, or cause an error. But, neither case is a character conversion, which is what I was initially addressing in terms of "data loss".